# Is it possible to auto update a text box when a NumericUpDown is updated

Tags: vb.net, auto-update

I'm trying to make my program so it auto updates the price in the text boxes for this "Pod" whenever I change the value of the NumericUpDown box by either +1 or -1

People.Value is the NumericUpDown Box

```
'Calculating and Displaying Prices for Liverpool Pod
    If cboxPod.Text = "Liverpool" = True And People.Value >= 0 Then
        TotalPrice.Text = "£" & (9 * People.Value)
        VAT.Text = ("£" & TotalPrice.Text * 0.2)
        Subtotal.Text = ("£" & TotalPrice.Text * 0.8)
    End If
```

Does anyone have any help?

Comment: Set `Option Strict On` before anything else. Then subscribe to the `ValueChanged` event of your NumericUpDown (or use a class object that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and use DataBindings to auto-update bound Controls). Assuming you're referring to a WinForms control. Specify the GUI framework in use.

Comment: If you want to do something when something else happens, that pretty much always means, first, determining what event is raised when the something else happens. It's just like you handle the Click event of a Button to do something when the Button is clicked. You're quite capable of reading the documentation for the NumericUpDown and finding out what events it has and when they are raised.

Answer (score 0):

For +1, write If X>0 then TotalPrice.Text =otalPrice.Text + "£" & (9 * People.Value):end if

For -1, write If X<0 then TotalPrice.Text =otalPrice.Text - "£" & (9 * People.Value):end if